# if (and) combination produces youve entered too many arguments for this function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have created following Formula, but it does not works:

```
=IF(AND(G2<41,L2<41),4,IF(AND(G2>40,G2<81),AND(L2>40,L2<81),5,IF(AND(G2>80,L2>80),6,IF(AND(G2>41,G2>81),AND(L2>80),7,IF(AND(G2<41,L2>40),AND(L2<81),8,IF(AND(G2<41,L2>80),9,IF(AND(G2>80,L2>40),AND(L2<81),3,IF(AND(G2>40,G2<81),AND(L2<41),2,IF(G2>81,L2<41),1,0)
```

Can anyone help me to improve the formula?

Comment: present you set of input values of G and L as a normal table, without the formula, for easy understanding of what values should result in what output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As AND is a binary operator requiring at least two argument to test that both are true, there four constructs having single conditions are wrong:

```
AND(L2>80), AND(L2<81), AND(L2<81), AND(L2<41)
```

in constructs like

```
AND(G2>41,G2>81)
```

that will hold true only if G2>81, so the first part, G2>41, is unnecessary, unless it should be     AND(G2>41,G2<81)

for wrong constructs like

```
IF(AND(G2>41,G2<81),AND(L2>80)
```

You should use

```
IF( AND( AND(G2>41,G2<81),L2>80))
```

That will first test that G2 is >41 as well as <81, and if that holds it will also check whether L2 is also >80

Answer (score 1):

If you take the single-digit numbers as intended for "result" for true tests, and then format the expression (formula) like this:

```
=IF( 
  AND(G2<41,L2<41),4,
  # else
    IF(AND(G2>40,G2<81),AND(L2>40,L2<81),5,
    # else
      IF(AND(G2>80,L2>80),6,
      # else
        IF(AND(G2>41,G2>81),AND(L2>80),7,
        #else 
          IF(AND(G2<41,L2>40),AND(L2<81),8,
          # else
            IF(AND(G2<41,L2>80),9,
            #else
              IF(AND(G2>80,L2>40),AND(L2<81),3,
              #else 
                IF(AND(G2>40,G2<81),AND(L2<41),2,
                # else 
                  IF(G2>81,L2<41),1,
                  # else
                  0)
```

... then it should be quite clear where the problem(s) exist.

Note that IF() takes ONE expression and tries whether it is TRUE or FALSE, returning the corresponding one of the two remaining arguments.

I'd recommend expressions/formulas to be kept as short as possible - it is very easy to end up with "a mess" otherwise - example here.

This is very similar to the situation where "smart code" is used for programming, i.e. where the remedy is: "KISS" (Keep it simple stupid).

Answer (score 0):

*Your Formula should written like this:*

```
=IF(AND(G2<41,L2<41),4,IF(AND(G2>40,G2<81,L2>40,L2<81),5,IF(AND(G2>80,L2>80),6,IF(AND(G2>41,G2<=81,L2>80),7,IF(AND(G2<41,L2>40,L2<81),8,IF(AND(G2<41,L2>80),9,IF(AND(G2>80,L2>40,L2<81),3,IF(AND(G2>40,G2<81,L2<41),2,IF(AND(G2>81,L2<41),1,0)))))))))
```

**Note:**

- I've done little modification and instead of

*IF(AND(G2>41,**G2>81**,L2>80),7*

I've written like this,

*IF(AND(G2>41,**G2<=81**,L2>80),7*

because the previous logic  `And(G2>80, L2>80)` for `6` was contradicting with *`IF(AND(G2>41,G2>81,L2>80),7`*